# Get folder of currently opened Pages document

Tags: applescript, pages

I need to get the path (without the name of the file itself) of the currently opened Pages document.

This works fine:

```
tell application "Pages"
  get name of front document
end tell
```

But for some reason

```
tell application "Pages"
  get path of front document
end tell
```

gives me an error (Pages got an error: Can’t get path of document 1.) The document is on disk and is properly saved. What might be a reason?

Comment: You can’t just guess or try terminology that looks like it would make sense - all the terms that an application provides (if any) are listed in its scripting dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
tell application "Pages" to set theFile to (get file of document 1) as text

tell application "Finder" to set containingFolder to (container of alias theFile) as alias
```